# Python example to access a php site(HTTPS) protected by PKI

Tags: python, https, openssl, pki

I am looking for a example code for how to implement a Python application to communicate with a php site over HTTPS and use PKI protection.

I probably will use pyOpenSSL and httplib.HTTPSConnection. My question is where can I find a site that uses PKI for authentication? (would Github do this?). Also, is there any sample code for how to implement? Please advise, thanks.

Comment: Do you understand what PKI means? It is not a "spice" to add into your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is use httplib.HTTPSConnection like you said. I tried the following and it worked for me.

Example:

```
    import httplib
    HOSTNAME = 'login.yahoo.com'
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(HOSTNAME)
    conn.putrequest('GET', '/')
    conn.endheaders()
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print response.read()
```

Make note that this does not do any verification of the server’s certificate.

If you want to verify the certificate then you may want to use [pyOpenSSL](https://launchpad.net/pyopenssl). My preferred option would actually be to extend urllib2. An example of this can be found in the following [article](http://www.muchtooscrawled.com/2010/03/https-certificate-verification-in-python-with-urllib2/).

Reference:
http://www.noah.org/wiki/Python_HTTPS_and_SSL
http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117004-ssl-client-authentication-over-https/ is helpful?